# A Macro to write a Private Macro in ThisWorkBook

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there was a way I could write a macro that would write a macro to the ThisWorkBook Workbook Open module???

Answer (score 1):

This page contains information about that, but beware that with Excel 2002+ the user must allow VBA project modification.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx